# Fastest way to code up hitting a URL

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, web-crawler

I need to login to a site, then hit a certain URL about a thousand times (with different params, of course).

The URL is something this:

```
http://www.foo.com/bar.asp?id=x    ' where x is the ID
```

Of course if I simply hit the URL without being logged, it will fail.
I am not very familiar with this type of work, but I would imagine that whatever the method I choose, it would have to support cookies.

I was thinking that I could create a winform app with a browser control and somehow drive it, but that seems like a massive overkill.

Is there a better way?

Comment: If you're just interested in doing a bit of quick stress-testing, grab yourself the following: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/993a8a36-5761-448f-889e-9ae58d072c09.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @Noon No, not stress-testing.  The forum has been overrun with spam, so I need to run the delete_topic.asp about a million times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are determined to do it in your code itself then i dont think any thing is stopping you from doing that.
HttpRequest and HttpResponse classes has pretty much everything you need to do that.

---

Moreover if you are concerned about cookies then you could always store received cookies in a database or file and send them with every subsequent request.

---

If you want to know the structure of the [Http Request like a GET request then look here](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/).

---

Also you can make your request look like a Request from browser by specifying the Proper Request Headers...(However it doesn't work every time)

**And all this can be done even in a console app**

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [WCAT](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1466) if you are mainly interested in how your server performs under load.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python or PHP, you can use the libcURL library, I believe they both have bindings for these languages. If not, just use the urllib2 module (for Python).

Comment: Hmmm, yeh, I saw the C# tag, but thought he was still asking in general. If you need C#, I think there is a binding for that too.